# How does Spring JPA with hibernate manage concurrent updates

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I am trying to write an app that can run active-active, with both instances using the same DB. I was worried that in updating a entity (calling repo.findById(), entity.setX(), repo.save(entity)) there was a potential race condition where updates could overwrite each other if there was a large enough delay between find and save.

To test it I made a method that loads the entity, waits 10 seconds, then adds something to a list attribute and saves it. Calling that twice I expected the second save to overwrite the first one, but surprisingly both updates were persisted.

Whilst this is what I wanted I was wondering if anyone knew how/why spring did this, because I want to make sure it will do this every time? I understand it uses optimistic locking by default, but you need the @version annotation (which I don't have). Will this also work if the updates come from separate apps, or did it only work because both of them were from the same application?

Comment: Simultaneous modifications in a database, no matter where they come from need to be handled with transactions correctly. The database doesn't care whether it has one connection from two apps, or two connections from one app. To the DB it's two connections and if they manipulate the same data, standard database precautions need to be followed.

Comment: So when I am saving the entity its only calling an SQL update on the fields that have changed since loading? Its not re-saving the whole object?

Comment: if you mark your entity with @DynamicUpdate then it will update only fields that you've changed. By default, it will update all object

Comment: But if it updates all of the object how does the second save not overwrite the original?